# Media players are showing duplicate files after moving them

Tags: internal-storage, file-system, file-transfer, files

So today I moved the entire 'Download'(which contains music and asmr I downloaded from YT with those mp3 sites) file from my phone storage, to my SD card. Then I went to my music player app and it showed the music and asmr titles double. I panicked and went to move back that file to my phone storage.

After I did it, I went to check my music player, and it showed me 3 times! I uninstalled the app and installed it back, but it still showed me double. I installed another music app, and it showed me just one time. I went back to the previous one and tried to play both titles to see if it works. The first title worked, but the second one didn't.

I checked the details of the songs, the first one showed me that it's from  **/storage/emulated/0/Download/(the title of the song).mp3** and the second one showed me **/storage/548F-6D80/Download/(the title of the song).mp3.** So I downloaded another music app, and it showed me double there too. I tried the same thing, it was the same, first worked, second didn't. So I tried to delete the second one(the one that didn't work) and it was deleted, but the first title remained.

I went to my first music player and it didn't show that music title twice again! So I did the same with the other ones, delete the one that doesn't work, and it didn't showed me double again! Right now I tried to move only the music to my SD card, to see if it would show me double again, and it didn't! Does anyone know what might have been the cause? I also searched the music titles(before I found the method to delete them) on my SD card, and it showed me the file with 0 items.
Maybe it showed me double because it saw only the file with 0 items in it?

Answer (score 0):

The music players get their information from the central Android Media Storage database (part of the Android OS), therefore both players were showing the same information.

When moving a large number of files around you have to keep calm and wait until the database has updated/re-scanned all entries. This happend automatically in background and can take some time depending on the number of files moved.

If after a few hours the situation is still not correct reboot the device, that should trigger a full re-scan of all media files.

Comment: you mean restart the phone? because when i accidentally rebooted my old phone, everything was deleted and i had to start from the start. Fortunately i was able to get everything back.