# full storage: internal storage counts external images

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, storage, photos

Android claims storage space is running out. `Settings > Storage` shows that `Photos & videos` take up 2 GB. See screenshot:
[image: storage settings]

However, I moved almost all camera photos to an external sd card. When I click on the last item, I get the message: `couldn't find item`, as shown in the screenshot.
It seems that the storage calculator counts the images moved to the external drive.
How can I fix this?

This is a Moto G5 with Android 8.1.0.

Comment: Th reason is similar to [this case](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230451/2241). The used space is not directly calculated but summarized based on the media database. And updating this database can take some time. To force an update reboot the phone and wait for ~30 minutes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)

Comment: @Robert: no, the problem persists after rebooting + waiting